# Using transactions in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm a learner of PHP. This commit and rollback process does the task at each line. How can I commit and rollback all at once?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','user', 'abcdefg');
if(!con)
{
    echo "Can't connect to db.";
}else {
    mysql_select_db('test');
}

if(!file_exits('test.csv')
{
    echo "Can't find the file.";
}

$ar_1 = file('test.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($ar_1 as $ar1)
{
    $test = explode(",", $ar1); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE CD = '$test[0]'";
    $result = mysql_query_($sql);   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO DB(CODE) VALUES ('$test[0]');";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result === true)
    {
        //Commit
        $sql = "commit";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "Committed";
    }else {
        //Rollback
        $sql = "rollback";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "Rollback";
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: did you get any error ? If yes then mentioned it here..

Comment: move the commit and rollback out of the loop , you're commiting in the foreach!

Comment: I did not get any error but I want to commit and rollback for all at once not each time.

Comment: Thank you i will move the commit and rollback out of the loop and update the status

Comment: Sun eel Kumar  Thank you sir for the correction i really appreciate.

Comment: You're using a deprecated MySQL extension for PHP which has been removed in PHP 7.0, so it would be a good idea to migrate to PDO/mysql or mysqli as soon as you can. This will allow you to use parameter binding, in order to avoid the potential SQL injection vulnerabilities that may be in this code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to commit out of the loop, i used `$bool` to see if there somewhere the `$result` isn't true

it will look something like :

**edit:**
breaking from the loop when something is wrong as you don't need to continue looping to other elements.

```
$bool = 1;  
      foreach ($ar_1 as $ar1)
      {
         $test = explode(",", $ar1);

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE CD = '$test[0]'";
         $result = mysql_query_($sql);

         $sql = "INSERT INTO DB(CODE) VALUES ('$test[0]');";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);

         if($result === false)
         {

             //Rollback
             $bool = 0;
             $sql = "rollback";
             mysql_query($sql);
             echo "Rollback";
             break;
         }

     }
     if($bool == 1)
     {
        //Commit
        $sql = "commit";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "Committed";
     }
    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Helped me a lot.

Comment: @Manish here's a better code, also, consider voting the answer as correct

Comment: I would like to appreciate and once again thank you above code was very much helpful.

Comment: Sorry once again above code was very much helpful to me. But I 'm looking for the method which stores the all of the data temporarily and do the transaction process at the end only. I think above code will commit each and every line of the data isn't it? Would you mind guiding me.

Comment: $bool = 0;  
      foreach ($ar_1 as $ar1)
      {
         $test = explode(",", $ar1);

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE CD = '$test[0]'";
         $result = mysql_query_($sql);

         $sql = "INSERT INTO DB(CODE) VALUES ('$test[0]');";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);

         if($result === false)
         {
   $bool++;
         }

     }
     if($bool == 0)
     {
        mysql_query("COMMIT");
        echo "Committed";
     }else {
      mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
      echo "Rollback";
     }
    mysql_close($con);

Comment: imagine we have 100 element in the loop, and in the first one have an error, in your version in the comments, we will have to keep trying to do the query even though we already know we will eventually rollback, in the edited version, we rollback as soon as there is an error! but we commit only **once** in the end if everything is fine *(if no query had a problem)*

Comment: Improve version will be like instead of '$bool ++;' if we do rollback then it will be no problem.

Comment: yes, that's the solution written in the answer above, instead of `$bool++` i rollback immediately and end the loop